# Missing missing return statement accepted by g++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int bar()
    {
        bool bla = false;
        auto lambda = [&]() -> int {
            if (bla)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            // return 1;
        };
        (void)lambda;
        return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar();
}
```

This example above perfectly compiles with g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0 and "-Wall -Wpedantic -Werror -Wextra".

However, e.g. https://cppinsights.io/ complains

```
/home/insights/insights.cpp:13:9: warning: non-void lambda does not return a value in all control paths [-Wreturn-type]
        };
        ^
1 warning generated.
```

Why does gcc not complain?

Comment: You need to specify `-pedantic` too for it to flag the missing return - weird imo.

Comment: pedantic is used, see the list of compile options `... -Wpedantic ...`

Comment: Right! I missed that.

Comment: It'll warn you if the lambda is used though it seems (e.g. replace  (void)lambda; with lambda(); )

Comment: @nos: Correct, g++  issues a warning (error due to `-Werror`) when using the lambda.

However, clang does without using it.
Additionally: In my original scenario there are code snippets that look quite similar, thouhg more complex. In template methods there are non-void returning lambdas which are definetly used. Not all paths of the lambda contain a return statement (developer missed that). But g++ does not warn about this issue. I wonder if that could be a known g++ issue.